# How to get a Python help in vim ? just like vim to use :h

Tags: python, vim, manual

How to get a python help in vim? just like vim to type :h
to get it.
I'm just a newer in python, but I need Python's manual page just easy as vim.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Access_Python_Help and http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=910

Comment: @FDinoff Better to forget about wiki, quality of advices here is so poor. This one contained a bunch of `map` while they should be using `nnoremap`. It also contained snippets like `execute "read !".shellescape(s:pydoc_path . " " . a:what)` which cannot work because in this case it will try to launch command like `"pydoc os.path"` while should be launching `"pydoc" "os.path"`. It is also using improper kind of escaping: `shellescape()` call for `!` must contain `, 1`: non-zero second optional argument. This “quality” I see always on almost any advice. // Note: check versions before my edits.

Comment: There is also [viewdoc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3893) BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're coding Python in vim, the `python-mode` plugin may prove useful: https://github.com/klen/python-mode#show-documentation

For example, if you move with your cursor over some python function/module etc. and press `K` in normal mode, its documentation will be displayed in a new buffer.